# Relation between topological and measurable subspaces

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological subspace and let $\Sigma(\mathcal{C})$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose $E \in \Sigma(\tau)$, and consider the topological structure:
$$
\tau' = \{F \in P(E): \exists U \in \tau: F=U \cap E\}
$$
and the measurable structure:
$$
M' = \{F \in P(E): \exists U \in \Sigma(\tau): F=U \cap E\}
$$
inherited by $E$ from $X$.

I would like to know what is the relation between $M'$ and $\Sigma(\tau')$. It is clear that $\Sigma(\tau') \subseteq M'$ because if $F \in \tau'$ then $F=U \cap E$ for some $U \in \tau \subseteq \Sigma(\tau)$ so that $F \in M'$, but what about the converse inclusion?

---

As always, any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the reverse inclusion, let $C$ be the set of $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\cap E\in \Sigma(\tau')$.  Then $C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\tau\subseteq C$, so $\Sigma(\tau)\subseteq C$.  This exactly says that $M'\subseteq \Sigma(\tau')$.